# X keyboard layout unable to toggle

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout, dwm

I don't understand why `alt_shift_toggle` is not triggers keyboard layout switch
This is what I have `localectl status`

```
System Locale: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
    VC Keymap: us
   X11 Layout: us,ru
    X11 Model: grp:alt_shift_toggle
```

After pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> nothing changes.

Comment: Your question does not clearly indicate whether you're trying to use that key combination to change X.org keyboard layout or virtual console keyboard layout. That key combination only works in X.org.

Comment: @RistoSalminen what is main difference between them? The only way I can change layout now is with `setxkbmap -layout ru`. Any suggestions?

Comment: X.org is the graphical environment, and virtual console is the text-only interface, which starts by default. But since you can change your layout via setxkbmap, it means that you are in X, so nevermind about my comment.

Comment: The output of your `localectl status` looks fishy to me; it shows the model as `grp:alt_shift_toggle`. A valid model is something like `pc105`. How are you setting up your keyboard layout? I suspect the error lies there.